# Problem with thread C#, randomly gives an error in which it says that the process is not started

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, console, race-condition

Problem with thread C#, randomly gives an error in which it says that the process "0" is not started.
the error occurs in p0.Join

```
namespace ThreadEsercitazione
{
    class Program
    {
        static int x = 89;
        static Thread p0 = new Thread(P0);
        static Thread p1 = new Thread(P1);
        static void P0()
        {
            x++;
            Console.WriteLine(x);
        }
        static void P1()
        {
            p0.Join(); //(Thread is not started)
            x--;
            Console.WriteLine(x);
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            p1.Start();
            p0.Start();

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Well, you are starting `p1` ***before*** `p0`, setting up decent conditions for the worst outcome of the race.

Comment: You are starting `p0` after `p1`, so the `Join` may be executed when `p0` is not yet running. You also modify a shared resource `x` without a lock statement or interlocked APIs. Also, please, for the love of your future colleagues, don't mix English and Italian.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, change the order of task starting. Additionally it will be worth to check that p0 is running before starting p1:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    p0.Start();
    if (p0.ThreadState == ThreadState.Running)
        p1.Start();

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to use ThreadPool and stuff but if you want to go with manually created foreground Thread's and you want them to start in the order you demonstrated - here's the solution (This might seem a little bit tricky):

**Main performers:**

[ManualResetEventSlim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.manualreseteventslim?view=netframework-4.8) - Represents a thread synchronization event that, when signaled, must be reset manually. This is one of the best sync tools that doesn't switch contexts. But be sure not to use it with long term blocking because it spins and if it takes longer than expected - resorts to a regular event handle wait!

[Interlocked](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.interlocked?view=netframework-4.8) - Provides atomic operations for variables that are shared by multiple threads.

**The code:**

```
    class Program
    {
        static ManualResetEventSlim mres = new ManualResetEventSlim(false);
        static int x = 89;
        static Thread p0 = new Thread(P0);
        static Thread p1 = new Thread(P1);

        static void P0()
        {
            Interlocked.Increment(ref x);
            Console.WriteLine(x);
        }
        static void P1()
        {
            while(true)
            {
                if (p0.ThreadState == ThreadState.Unstarted)
                    mres.Wait();
                else
                    break;
            }

            p0.Join(); 
            Interlocked.Decrement(ref x);
            Console.WriteLine(x);
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            p1.Start();
            p0.Start();

            mres.Set(); // This will "kick off" the mres spinning inside P1
            mres.Dispose();

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

    }
```

**Side notes**

**Do not use** lock operator or Monitor when you 100% sure your blockings won't last long. These are hybrid sync constructions that might switch the execution context which is not very good for performance. Also even if you get an exception within lock operator it will "unblock" your thread anyways as it translates in try / finally and uses Monitor.Exit within the finally block under the hood. So the next thread might get the access to damaged data.

**Use** Monitor when you know that your locks will last long or you're not sure about it. As it will eventually block your thread and there won't be livelocks or constant rollings.